# Making shared_ptr from the raw pointer of another shared_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Say, I have a `shared_ptr<A> ptrFirst`, that is initialized and is pointing to some object in memory. Now, I define a new `shared_ptr` like this:

```
shared_ptr<A> ptrSecond = make_shared<A>(ptrFirst.get());
```

I know that I could use simple assignment to prevent any issues. But I wonder if I define ptrSecond this way, will I have two different control blocks for the same object? Is this even bad?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the destructor. TLDR: It's bad.

Comment: Here yet another case where an actual [mcve] would have helped tremendously, because it would have uncovered the problems that others have pointed out.  That, in turn, would have lead to either not needing to ask the question, or to ask a much better question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a constructor that takes `A*` as only argument, your line won't event compile.

If you do have a constructor `A::A(A*)`, then `make_shared` will create a new object - this is fine.

If you would use `std::shared_ptr` constructor instead:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> ptrSecond = std::shared_ptr<A>(ptrFirst.get());
```

then it is a problem. It will result in double deallocation, which is UB.

Answer (score 2):

> But I wonder if I define ptrSecond this way, will I have two different control blocks for the same object?

No. This code:

```
shared_ptr<A> ptrSecond = make_shared<A>(ptrFirst.get());
```

is logically equal to:

```
shared_ptr<A> ptrSecond( new A( ptrFirst.get() ) );
```

so basically it will create new instance of `A` and initialize it with pointer to another `A`, of course it would compile only if you have proper ctor defined.

> Is this even bad?

If you mean something like this:

```
    shared_ptr<A> ptrSecond( ptrFirst.get() );
```

yes this is bad as it will lead to UB due to double deallocation.

Comment: Worse than that, you'll also get UB if you try to use the second pointer after the first has been destroyed.